# No Storage Bucket defined in Firebase Options. Updating Profile Photo into Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2, angularfire

I am having an error when trying to update the profile photo into the firebase db.

User.dashboard.html = User.editprofile.html

user-dashboard.html

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file" id="file"
 class="uploadPhoto" (change)="uploadPhotoURL($event)">
```

user-dashboard.ts

```
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireUploadTask} from '@angular/fire/storage';

  task: AngularFireUploadTask;

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private storage: AngularFireStorage,
  ) { }
 uploadPhotoURL(event): void {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const path = `users/${this.user.uid}/photos/${file.name}`;
    if (file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image') {
      return alert('only images allowed'); // When this is not an image!
    } else {
      this.task = this.storage.upload(path, file);

      // add this ref
      const ref = this.storage.ref(path);

      // and change the observable here
      ref.getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => {
        this.userService.updateProfileData(this.user.displayName, url);
      });
    }
  }
```

Upon inserting in an img file the file should be automatically uploaded into my db.

However I am faced with this error:

ERROR Error: No Storage Bucket defined in Firebase Options. @user.dashboard.html @  `<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file" id="file" class="uploadPhoto" (change)="uploadPhotoURL($event)">`

Comment: Please edit the question to explain exactly how you integrated Firebase into your app.  It seems to be missing a configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake.... never configure my storage inside firebase. 
In environment.ts

strorageBucketid: ''

Comment: However now... I am facing with another error when I am uploading the image...

Comment: GET https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ng-fire-version-ii.appspot.com/o/users%2FQF6cFNgdNUX02Cgkx9smCrmZtDA2%2Fphotos%2Fyvon-carre-168%5B1%5D.jpg 404

Comment: ERROR FirebaseStorageError {code_: "storage/object-not-found", message_: "Firebase Storage: Object 'users/QF6cFNgdNUX02Cgkx9…DA2/photos/yvon-carre-168[1].jpg' does not exist.", serverResponse_: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 404,↵    "message": "No…not get object",↵    "status": "GET_OBJECT"↵  }↵}", name_: "FirebaseError"}